# Difference between web application architecture and design pattern?

Tags: django, design-patterns, architecture

I need to develop a photo album web app in Django, stored on cloud services, with user login authentication, metadata and database. It must be developed according to a specific software design pattern that is different to the architectural pattern chosen. Please explain the difference between design and architectural patterns. Any industry acceptable suggestions on these patterns, suitable for a small project as explained above, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, "design patterns" would apply for "small decisions", like using singleton classes, abstract factories, or observable objects. It's not tied strictly to an architectural pattern like MVC or microservices, you build your whole system around that pattern. That's what I understand from the differences between architectural and design patterns.